# Spring Data JPA: AccessType.Field empty response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot 2.2.6
Spring Data JPA 2.2.7

I created an entity and placed the field annotation above the field. This should ensure that the access type is "field" - but it doesn't. 
If I make a request, I get no error and the response is an array with empty objects.
If I place the corresponding getter into the class, then everything works. Can you see, where I forgot something?

**entity**

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"})
public class Club implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

**controller**

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ClubController {

    @Autowired
    private ClubRepository clubRepository;

    @GetMapping("/clubs")
    List<Club> getAllClubs() {
        return clubRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**log**

```
logging.level.org.hibernate = DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web = DEBUG

2020-05-06 12:47:08.365 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]     
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/clubs", 
parameters={}
2020-05-06 12:47:08.365 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to 
com.manager.api.club.ClubController#getAllClubs()
2020-05-06 12:47:08.369 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : On TransactionImpl 
creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false 
2020-05-06 12:47:08.369 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2020-05-06 12:47:08.371 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.h.q.c.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl       : Rendered criteria query -> 
select generatedAlias0 from Club as generatedAlias0
2020-05-06 12:47:08.371 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        club0_.id as id1_0_ 
    from
        Club club0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        club0_.id as id1_0_ 
    from
        Club club0_
2020-05-06 12:47:08.372 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2020-05-06 12:47:08.373 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: 
EntityKey[com.manager.api.club.Club#1]
2020-05-06 12:47:08.373 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 1
2020-05-06 12:47:08.373 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: 
EntityKey[com.manager.api.club.Club#2]
2020-05-06 12:47:08.373 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for 
[com.manager.api.club.Club#1]
2020-05-06 12:47:08.373 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity 
[com.manager.api.club.Club#1]
2020-05-06 12:47:08.373 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for 
[com.manager.api.club.Club#2]
2020-05-06 12:47:08.373 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity 
[com.manager.api.club.Club#2]
2020-05-06 12:47:08.373 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2020-05-06 12:47:08.375 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 
'application/json;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, 
image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed- 
exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/json, 
application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2020-05-06 12:47:08.376 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing 
[[com.manager.api.club.Club@59ae401f, 
com.manager.api.club.Club@6afd7de2]]
2020-05-06 12:47:08.379 DEBUG 6379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Comment: What error do you get? And how do you get an error and a result at the same time?

Comment: This could be related to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1576 if this is the case making the id package private might be a possible workaround.

Comment: I updated my post. As metioned, i get no error. It looks like the annotation above the property has no effect on the access type. Even if I put an @Access(AccessType.Field) on the class it has no effect.

Comment: Got it. For external access, a getter method has to be implemented, independent of the access type.
Description when to omit getters:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#access (grey container)

Sounds self-explaining. AccessType.Field made me think that no getter methods are needed, because the access is done directly to the class attributes via reflection. But that is not the case.